# How to upgrade icinga2 libraries after the OS upgarde from rhel6 to rhel7.7?

Tags: devops, rhel7, rhel6, icinga2

I have upgraded the OS from `rhel6` to `rhel7.7`.
After up-gradation, The system showing error when I start `icinga2`.

Here the error is:

```
/usr/lib64/icinga2/sbin/icinga2: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.42: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please first make sure everything is up to date with `yum update`.How did you install icinga2? Can you show your repo list (`yum repolist`)?

Comment: http://packages.icinga.com/epel/7Server/release/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://packages.icinga.com/epel/7Server/release/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.

Comment: I do not have such timeout on this url. Can you try with packages6.icinga.com instead of packages.icinga.com ?

Comment: -bash: http://packages6.icinga.com/epel/7Server/release/repodata/repomd.xml:: No such file or directory